# Javascript array holds remove function

Tags: javascript

I am using a an array called "workingLinks", in my javascript function first I define the array as

```
workingLinks = [];
```

Then I use console

```
console.log(workingLinks);
```

Now the console displays as

```
[remove: function] ;
```

here if i use a `for` loop it is iterating over the function which i don't want. If I create an array in console then it works fine, shows `[]` as expected.  Anybody have the idea of how the array holds remove function?

Comment: Looks like you or your frameworrk added a `remove` method to the `Array` prototype.

Comment: yes I am using d3 framework with other few libraries, how to remove this temporarily?

Comment: D3 itself doesn't appear to be the culprit: http://jsfiddle.net/aqa60c43/2/. Check your other libraries if they mess with the `Array` prototype.

Comment: can I remove the function from prototype?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, since the `remove` function is probably being used elsewhere, but try: `delete Array.prototype.remove`

Comment: any easy way to identify the declaration? I have so many (4-5 ) libs

Comment: If you want to get rid of the remove function, add `hasOwnProperty` checks to your `for.. in` loop (or use a `for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i)` loop instead, since you're using arrays).

Comment: [This is why you should _never_ use `for..in` with arrays.](http://kera.name/articles/2011/09/a-brief-introduction-to-javascript-objects-arrays/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the remove function, the guys in the comments were pretty helpful.

However, you can simply iterate an array with the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function like so:

```
arr.forEach(functionToRunForEachElement);
```

It also accepts anonymous functions:

```
arr.forEach(function(element, index, originalArray) {
   //Do stuff here
});
```

There are also [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to perform common actions like mapping all the values of the array to something else, or reduce the array of values into a single value.

Comment: Note that `forEach` will only work in browsers that support ES5, but you can find shims for older browsers, or use a libraries like underscore and lodash, which have an `each` utility method that works on arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Something has modified the Array prototype. I tried this in Chrome:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function () {};
> function () {}
console.log([]);
> [remove: function]
```

What other libraries are you using?